# What's wrong with my java program, "illegal start of expression error"

Tags: java

I'm a very beginner in JAVA, I can't run my project.

cmd said `<identifier>expected;illegal start of expression;not a statement; ';'expected              totally 5 errors`

```
public class 1 {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    int A=2;
    int B=2;
    System.out.println(A);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why can't you run it?  What, specifically, is stopping you?

Comment: `1` cannot be used as class name - use a name, e.g. `One` or `Test1`.

Comment: `Unclear what you're asking`? I think it's pretty obvious what he's asking. He can't run that snippet. He even posted the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't name your class a numeral `1`.

```
public class 1{ // <-- no
```

should be something like

```
public class One { // <-- the word one is fine
```

or (if possible) something meaningful like

```
public class Example { // <-- for example.
```

Comment: Well, *Example* isn't very meaningful, too :D. But I know what you mean.

Answer (score 3):

This is due to the fact that you started your class name with a number.

> A variable's name can be any legal identifier — an unlimited-length sequence of Unicode letters and digits, beginning with a letter.

From the [Official Oracle Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html/).

You are only permitted characters, or an underscore in the beginning of a variable, object, or class name.

The following are OK:

```
public class one{
...
}

public class _one{
...
}

public class classOne{
...
}

public class class_one{
...
}
```

Or anything that *only contains a character or underscore as the first character.

Generally, classes are named **After the parent file**, for example, the file `main.java` would start off with `public class Main{...}`.

Answer (score 0):

This is my first ever answer, so I hope it satisfies. Feel free to ask for clarification.

Two things, and they seem to have been touched on by other answers, too.

1. You can have numbers IN your class name, but not starting a class name. so:

class a1

would be fine. It also defies (at least) convention to start your class name with an underscore or a dollar sign. Letters, and whole words are best practice.

2. Be sure to include the public static void main(String args[]) {}.
   main()   ..lower case... is a special, reserved name that the system will look for and try to run first.
   (edit: it looks like my public static void main line might not be displaying properly here. [This is what it should look like.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/))